# Real Numbers [0,inf)

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers

On the interval $[0, \infty)$, are all the real numbers perfect square? I am trying to prove that the function of real numbers on the interval $[0, \infty)$ such that $f(x) = x^2+1$ is not one to one.

Comment: But it is one-one on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: Yes, every nonnegative real number is a square of a real number.

Comment: Why not $f$ is 1 to 1?

Comment: Well, there is **no $x$** for which $f(x)= x^2 + 1 = 0$.  In fact, $f(x)\geq 1$.  So the function is not onto, because there are no values $x$ which will be mapped anywhere on the interval $[0, 1)$.  I thought the question was whether $f(x)$ on the given domain is a one-to-one correspondence, which it is not.  However, $f(x) = x^2$ on $[0, \infty)$ is indeed a one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: Suppose that $f$ weren't one-to-one... then that would mean that you have some $a$ and $b$ such that $0\leq a<b$ and $f(a)=f(b)$ which would imply that $a^2+1=b^2+1$ which would imply that $a^2=b^2$.  But... $0\leq a<b$... so...

Comment: "Perfect square" means square of an integer. So the answer is technically "no," but if you meant to ask if every real number in $[,\infty)$ is the square of a real number in $[0,infty)$, then yes, but not a useful fact for this purpose as far as I can see.

Comment: Why do you want to prove it's one-to-one?